# Adjusting the gridview and roe of buttons

Tags: java, android, gridview

- I am trying to adjust the space between grid view and buttons
- I have posted figure
- I am trying to attain that

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Top navigation bar for Restaurant Description Page -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#726E6D" >

            <!-- Back Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDescActivityBackButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="13dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:text="BACK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <!-- Restaurant Description page name -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDescActivityName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Restaurant Description page Image -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDescActivityImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RestaurantTimingsID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timings"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/BuyReservedButtonRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2sp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buy_button_shape"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="13dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:text="Buy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ReservedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/reserverd_button_shape"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="13dp"
            android:paddingRight="13dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:text="Reserve"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionTitleRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2sp" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >
            </GridView>
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantDescriptionButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantLocationButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantPhotosButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Photos"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantFriendsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantSearchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantFeaturedButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Featured"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantDealsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Deals"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantInviteButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Invite"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RestaurantAccountButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_square_shape"
                    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingRight="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Account"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

## How to remove the space between the grid view and below row of buttons

How to remove the space below gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below segment of code, replace with your code and pls check once.

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionTitleRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2sp" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >
            </GridView>
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: if you found this answer useful then accept it, so other people can use it without doubt.